# Buttons with layout_weight="1" take all space in LinearLayout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I want to put 4 buttons horizontally in a linearlayout. In order to space them equally I set `android:layout_weight="1"` in each button. The problem is that the width of the button is not respected and they fill the whole linearlayout. This works with imageviews, why not with buttons?

Thanks

[image]

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp" android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_sort_pert"
        android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/pertinence"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sort" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_sort_dist"
        android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/distance"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sort" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_sort_prix"
        android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/prix"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sort" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_refine"
        android:layout_width="32dp" android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/btn_affiner" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is no problem with the code on my emulator. Can you attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

You need to add empty views like:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dp" android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_sort_pert"
        android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/pertinence"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sort" />
       <View android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="1dp" 
       android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_sort_dist"
        android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/distance"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sort" />
     <View android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="1dp" 
      android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_sort_prix"
        android:layout_width="90dp" android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/prix"
        android:textSize="14sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_sort" />
     <View android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="1dp" 
     android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_refine"
        android:layout_width="32dp" android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/btn_affiner" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It makes the buttons invisible, I guess because they have no height... My code works if I replace the Buttons by ImageViews.

Comment: @jul: he probably missed the fact that it's a horizontal layout, try width = 0px

Comment: I think @jul wants to space the buttons equally horzontally and not to make them of equal width..

Comment: Ah k, read it wrong the first time. Now i guess it will do what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

With those settings the `ImageView` is behaving like the `Button`, but you don't see that probably because by default the images will be centered if they're not filling the view in width. It's like a frame, you'll see that with *HierarchyViewer* (an SDK tool to debug layouts).

If I get what you want, to do the same with buttons you'll have to enclose each button in a layout, so that the enclosing layouts will share evenly the space, and the buttons can stay gravity-centered into those layouts, each with its own width, having a sort of flexible "margin" at their sides. (not tested but should work!)

Comment: Alternately a solution I've used is to intersperse empty Views in between the buttons, and give just the empty Views layout_weights. The buttons will keep their width, and the empty Views will fill the remaining space equally. You may even try giving both the Views and the Buttons layout_weights, just give the Buttons a larger weight than the empty Views. This will be adaptable to more screen sizes and densities.